# Where can I find an ability that prevents True Seeing from penetrating a transformation?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, content-identification, shapeshifting, disguise

Recently, I read a comment or forum post saying that there was an ability, to the best of my recollection it was a feat in a *Dragon* [Magazine] issue, which would negate *[true seeing](http://dndsrd.net/spellsTtoZ.html#true-seeing)* vs. shape changing. I have been unable retrace my steps, and have come up dry in my search of indices.

I'd like to find the issue number, or other location, if such an ability exists.

Comment: I’m not aware of anything like this, but I have a character who’d love it if true!

Comment: How Mind Blank is ruled to interact with divinations like True Seeing in your game? There is an opinion, that it stops them completely (with respect to shielded person only). So True Seeing won't be able to get its caster the information, that a random guy next to him is actually a changeling who stalks him.

Comment: @annoyingimp Yes, _depending on the DM/Table_, it *can* work. For non-casters, and even some casters, it's also an expensive option to my eye.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect that, instead of a feat, what was discussed in that comment was the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell ***cloak of Khyber*** (*Dragon* #337 59 and *City of Stormreach* 59). In addition to other effects, the spell for 1 day per caster level "shields a shapechanged or magically disguised creature from *true seeing*, causing the disguise to appear to be the caster’s true form" so long as the disguise was maintained for at least 6 hours prior.

So far as I'm aware, this spell's effects are unique. For example, I searched my list of 2,500 or so *Dungeons & Dragons, Third Edition* feats, inclusive, for, separately, *disguise* and *true seeing* and found no feat from *Dragon* or elsewhere that had an effect like the *cloak of Khyber* spell.

Comment: Why so few feats? The official Consolidated List of feats shows 3276 results, though some of those are duplicates from different sources.

Comment: @nijineko One day I'll count all the feats, but the document's nearly 2,800 pages with no dupes yet includes all licensed products… and a lot of notes. You're right, though, 2 per page is probably a better estimate, so likely over 5,000. It's been some time since I had to put a number to it.

Comment: That sounds like a great resource, thanks for looking. Did you try the keywords *reveal*, *divination spell*, *true form*, or *natural form*?

Comment: @Chemus I will when I get a chance, but I'm nearly 100% certain that nothing will come of it. I've DMed enough shapechangers to know what feats—and spells, obviously,—are good for them, and a feat that did what the question describes would be near the top of that list. Still, I am less versed in magic items than spells and feats, so there may yet be a magic item out there that does this trick.

Comment: Thanks. I'm simply hoping your resources are different than mine, as I came up blank through what I have. There's every possibility that I misread the comment, or that the commenter was mistaken in some fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Not a feat and not a spell, but one option that might work* is taking all 7 levels in the Spymaster prestige class (*Complete Adventurer*).

Unfortunately it's not going to fit many builds, but I felt like this set of answers was not complete without at least mentioning the possibility.

---

*When impersonating one of your cover identities, divination spells detect only information relative to the cover identity.

Whether your shape is "information" and something a divination spell "detects" is something your DM has to decide: it almost surely foils divinations where you ask information like *commune* and I only hope it protects you from *true seeing* (because I would really like to play a character like that, one day), but given how it is written asking how the DM wants to read it is important.

Comment: Yes, this, as well as *mind blank* (*Player's Handbook* (2003), 253) http://dndsrd.net/spellsMtoO.html#mind-blank can be read as protecting against detection, though each is quite expensive in its own way.